# Extract 1 file from tar.gz with bash

Tags: linux, bash, gzip, tar

Is it possible to programmatically pull a single file from a decently sized .tar.gz without extracting the entire tarball to disk?  Essentially I need to get inside large tar.gz files over the network and extract 1 small text file. It seems somewhat over-the-top to pull and extract the tarball to disk, then pull the file out, then delete everything else.  Also I'm going to be doing this recursively (e.g. package dependencies, each text file points to more tar.gz's), so the less network traffic and cpu cycles I can get away with, the better.

Comment: Nah, it's bash related. And bash is programming (kind of).

Comment: @Matt Joiner: It's not really bash-related. It's a usage question for a common system utility that can be called from any shell, not just bash. But yes, programming in bash is indeed program, despite what you may have heard sometimes here.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about SU but it's inside a relatively complex bash script, and it's going to be run via machine not by a user, so I figured it was a little more SO than SU.

Comment: Well, I don't personally mind; not about to start a crusade or anything. But I've seen questions plenty more programming-related migrated to SU. (And really, though you're using it for programming, the answer doesn't depend on that.) Oh well. Rep for me!

Comment: Good point.  I really don't mind either way, that was just how I was looking at it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the man page, to extract blah.txt from foo.tar.gz:

```
tar -xzf foo.tar.gz blah.txt
```

(And this goes on superuser, of course, but hey, prompt answers are nice too.)

Comment: Will this work if the file is located in a sub-directory inside the tar.gz structure?

Comment: With modern versions of GNU tar, you don't have to specify the 'z' option on extract - it will deduce that itself (and similarly with the 'j' option for bzip2 compressed files).  When creating the file, you do need the option to tell tar what to create - so symmetry does no harm whatsoever.

Comment: @tj111: if the file name in the tar file is `xyz/pqr/abc.txt`, that is what you specify in the command line.  You can use shell-style metacharacters too: `xyz/pqr/*` will extract all the files in all the sub-directories under `xyz/pqr`.  Just be wary of whether the shell expands the '*' for you - use quotes to stop it doing so.

Comment: @tj111: Yes, of course. And it will create the directories to hold the single file.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Yeah, true; I thought about that, but figured I'd quote the manpage literally.

Answer (score 4):

I echo Jefromi's answer, with the addition of including the path to the file if you have directories in the tar file (this may seem obvious to some, but it wasn't initially clear to me how to specify the directory structure).

For example, if you did the tar at the src/ directory, and blah.txt was under release1/shared/, you would go back to the src/ directory (if you want it untarred at the same place)

```
tar -xzf tar.gz release1/shared/blah.txt
```

If you don't remember the directory structure of your tar file (I'm a little disorganized and sometimes forget where I did the tar), you can always

```
tar -tzf tar.gz
```

to see the contents, canceling out (Ctrl+C) once you get an idea of your directory structure.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Although it appears you need a `./` in front of the directories for whatever reason to scan into them. e.g. `tar -xzf tar.gz ./release1/shared/blah.txt`